# Randomization in Tableau

Tags: random, tableau-desktop

I am trying to generate random numbers in Tableau between 1 and 15. Currently, I am using the Random() function. However, this returns random numbers in the [0,1] interval. Does anyone know how to get whole integer values instead?

I am using this feature to try to both randomize and anonymize the names of 15 people.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually `random` is the function you should look for, even thought it returns numbe from 0 to 1.

According to the integer number you are trying to get, why don't you multiply the result by 10/100/1000/etc and then use the `round` function in order to get rid of the rest?

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. But I do not like this solution because when I use the same calculated field in two different charts, it gives me completely different answers. in one place, John Doe has number 89 and in another place John Doe has number 71. This doesn't work well for me because I am trying to use the same random number for John Doe everywhere.